# making concrete object to type "Object" loses properties

Tags: c#

if I have the following class

```
Person {
 string FirstName {get;set;}
 string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

and in another class I do the following

```
OtherClass {
 List<Person> personList = new List<Person(/*10 people in here*/);
 List<Object> personObjectList = new List<Object>();
 foreach (Person p in personList) {
  personObjectList.Add(p);
 }
}
```

then I try to do

```
personObjectList[0].FirstName;
```

why is it not recognized that this object has a `FirstName` property? I didn't realize changing the type of object makes it lose its properties.

Thank you

Comment: You should convert `Object` to `Person` explicitly: `(personObjectList[0] as Person).FirstName`

Comment: Well, its an MVC application and I'm doing this partially in the controller and then partially in the view, and the problem is that the view doesn't know about the models... so type Person is unknown to the view

Comment: Use strongly typed views?

Comment: You can use `dynamic` instead of `object`... Also there likely strongly typed solution too (but you need to provide more details on what does not work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main choices. In order of what I suggest.. they are:

Create view models per view. These are objects in your UI layer that represent specific data for individual views. You map your domain models to view models in your controller. Libraries like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) and [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) can help you remove a lot of plumbing code in this regard. Just be careful *not to introduce business logic into your mappings*.

This has two main benefits:

- Your view can use strongly typed view models instead of casting everywhere
- Your view models and domain models can evolve independently

That second point is **very** important. When you allow your views to use domain models directly, you fall into a lot of big traps. The biggest is that you will start using `Html.HiddenFor` (`<input type="hidden"/>`) *everywhere* to persist data between pages - and this very very quickly becomes a nightmare for you to deal with.

Also, having separate view models allows the models to evolve independently. Your domain model may have properties relating to business need - but your view model can contain properties that relate purely to UI concerns. Things like UI level validation, aggregation properties (such as `FullName` in the view model instead of `FirstName` + `Surname`). The flexibility is really really nice to have.

Secondly, against everything I have said above - you can just place a `@using` directive at the top of your view to include the namespace where your objects are. This allows you to use the models in the view.

..I strongly suggest you investigate the first option I provided you though. You'll feel better for it later on in your project.

Comment: No problem. I have seen _many_ projects turn in to soup because of domain objects being in views. So many times have I seen `@Html.HiddenFor` be placed into a view for the specific purpose of storage ... its annoying to deal with when debugging and certainly the wrong way to do things.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't lose its properties; the compiler just doesn't know they exist. To get the properties you need to cast it back to a `Person`.

```
name = ((Person)personObjectList[0]).FirstName;
```

or

```
var person = personObjectList[0] as Person;
if (person != null)
    name = person.FirstName;
```

The first style will throw an exception if the cast fails. The second style will return `null` if the cast fails, so you should check for `null` if you do it that way.

Comment: can't cast because its in the view, which doesn't know about the models, but I see what you're saying

Comment: @AbdulAhmad You have two options. Firstly, you can pop a `@using` directive at the top of the view so the view _does_ know about those models. Otherwise, you can introduce a "view model" entity that maps your domain objects to models specifically for the view. I suggest option two so that they can grow independently (which they often do).

Comment: simon... why not make it an answer! or @aj_r edit your answer :)